# Change Siri's default search engine on macOS

Tags: macos, siri, search-engine

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to macOS Sierra and now have access to Siri. Whenever Siri searches the internet, it uses Bing, although I would prefer to use Google.

I changed Safari's default search engine to Google, but that did not affect Siri's searches.

How can I change Siri's default search engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, there's no way to change the default macOS Siri search engine.

I would recommend letting Apple know you'd like the ability to change the search engine using the [macOS Feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the default, but if you ask Siri to 'Google x' Siri will do just that.